Need Help Fetching Subcategories and Images from CS-Cart Backend for E-Commerce Flutter App
i am trying to build an e-commerce application using Flutter and cs-cart as the backend the problem is when I create categories in the backend they have images and sub-categories when I fetch these categories in my app with the provided endpoint by cs-cart it receives all the categories with sub and some of the parents not all of them in documentation it says Categories will have for example this field main_pair but when I retrieve it it does not have that anyone has a solution
